# Hide image automatically after 5 sec

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an gif image in my project.When i click a button it should appear and after 5 sec it should dissapear from the screen. I tried using j query to do this.But i am not getting the output.Where i might gone wrong?

Below is my code i tried so far:

**Jquery:**

```
 $(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { $("#btnEmail").fadeOut(1500); }, 5000)
        $('#btnMail').click(function () {

            $('#btnEmail').show();
            setTimeout(function () { $("#btnEmail").fadeOut(1500); }, 5000)
        })
    })
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEmail"  runat="server" onclick="btnMail_Click" Visible="false">
   <asp:Image ID="Image8" imageurl="~/Images/email_animation.gif" runat="server" class="box" /> </asp:LinkButton>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnMail"  runat="server" Text="Send" onclick="btnMail_Click"/>
```

**btnMail_Click**(Code Behind):

```
btnMail.Visible = false;
btnEmail.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As You are using ASP.NET Controls generated ID of elements will be different.

You should use [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property.

> Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

Use

```
 $(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#<%= btnEmail.ClientID %>").fadeOut(1500);
    }, 5000)
    $('#<%=btnMail.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        $('#<%=btnEmail.ClientID %>').show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#<%=btnEmail.ClientID %>").fadeOut(1500);
        }, 5000)
    })
 })
```

Comment: Line 349:        $('#<%=btnMail').click(function ()

Comment: @Maes, that was typo, I missed `.ClientID %>`, Updated now try once again

Answer (score 2):

there is a chance the clientId (the id the element get on browser) is different than the Id you mentioned. you should use ClientId property to set the id the control will receive on client.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ClientID="btnEmail"  runat="server" onclick="btnMail_Click" Visible="false">
```

[ClientID on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You have to Give ClientID

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%= btnEmail.ClientID %>").click(function () {

        $("#<%=Image8.ClientID %>").show();
        setTimeout(function () { $("#<%=Image8.ClientID %>").hide()}, 5000)
    })
});
```

Please ref: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4n4X/)